# Why database is not seeded?

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-identity-2

Well, i am quite novice in asp.net identity. Now there is a task to provide some seed data (user with administrator role). Trying to use code similar [Asp identity samples](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples).

I have some static class which has several methods for seeding data, most of them use native EF update tools (DbSet.AddOrUpdate) and these work fine. And last one uses new identity API:

```
private static void InitRolesAndAdminProfile(PortalContext context)
        {
            var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            const string name = "webadmin";
            const string email = "webadmin@mail.ru";
            const string password = "StrongKeyword1";
            var rolenames = new[]
            {
                "Administrator",
                "Judge",
                "Competitor",
                "Member"
            }; 
     foreach (string rolename in rolenames)
            {
                CustomIdentityRole role = roleManager.FindByName(rolename);
                if (role == null)
                {
                    role = new CustomIdentityRole { Name = rolename };
                    IdentityResult roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
                }
            }

            UserProfile user = userManager.FindByName(name);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new UserProfile { UserName = name, Email = "webadmin@mail.ru", NickName = name };
                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(user, password);
                result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
            }

            // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
            IList<string> rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
            CustomIdentityRole adminrole = roleManager.FindByName(rolenames.First());
            if (!rolesForUser.Contains(adminrole.Name))
            {
                IdentityResult result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, adminrole.Name);
            }         
        }
```

This is my controller's test code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new PortalContext())
        {
           context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

But problem is that when code's execution reaches some IO-operations (UserManager.Create, UserManager.FindByName and similar for other managers) the  application hangs indefinitely. Seed method is executed in DropCreateDbAlways derived class.

Anyway database is constructed properly and i can see its schema in server explorer, which means that there are no connection string related problems.

What is going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Noticed some strange thing: if i set `true` value here:

```
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Everything works fine. Supposedly i don't know any important details of work EF itself. But why is this happening? Question is still opened.

Comment: If your IO operation is hanging the application, that means that one of the Async operations is not awaited. Though I don't see `async` anywhere, I'd suggest trying to convert your operations to `*Async` versions and check if  this fixes the problem. From there you'll have more info about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried seeding from your database initializer? You shouldn't need to call Initialize() from a controller action except in rare cases where you have a ton of seeding and want to control when it runs. Your context constructor should set the initializer:

```
static ApplicationDbContext()
{
   // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
   // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
   Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
}

public class ApplicationDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{

     protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
     {
         InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
         base.Seed(context);
     }

     public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
     {
        if (!db.Users.Any())
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

            // Add missing roles
            var role = roleManager.FindByName("Admin");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
            ...

            // Create test users
            var user = userManager.FindByName("admin");
            if (user == null)
            {
                 var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
                 {
                      UserName = "admin",
                      FirstName = "Admin",
                      LastName = "User",
                      Email = "xxx@xxx.net",
                      PhoneNumber = "5551234567",
                      MustChangePassword = false
                 };
                 userManager.Create(newUser, "Password1");
                 userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(newUser.Id, false);
                 userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "Admin");
             }
             ...
```

See http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Comment: thanks, but  i mentioned, that  Seed method is executed in DropCreateDbAlways derived class. And i know that if some conditions are true for according to concrete initializer, Initializiation begins with any first request to db via my context. But i have no need to do request: i am just testing my seeding now. Therefore i force initialization explicitly. In what i am wondering now is **why** IO-methods works well with `true` value and don't otherwise.(see update section).

Comment: Do you have a single context derived from IdentityDbContext or do you have them separated?

Comment: Yeah, i have the only one. Try to reproduce - it is done quickly. Btw, i set my initializer in global.asax, not in static constructor. The same behavior with other initializers (createifnotexist, dropcreateifmodelchanges).

Comment: I ran into some issues where initialization ran before the Owin stuff was ready. When I switched to RoleStore and UserStore etc it started working as expected.

Comment: Upvoted for ur efforts, but still have no understanding how this actually works. While debugging i see that UserManager and RoleManager are being resolved, they are not null, therefore OwinContext (supposedly owin stuff) exists, i quess.